# How to return the default value of the NanoCpus parameter?

Tags: docker

NanoCpus default setting is 0.
But if we update the container, we get the value 1000000000.

```
docker update --cpus "1"  conainer
docker inspect --format='{{.HostConfig.NanoCpus}}' conainer
```

How to restore value 0 in NanoCpus?

Comment: With the commands you show, you're setting a limit of 1 CPU, or 1,000,000,000 nano-CPUs; that seems consistent to me.  Why would you expect it to be 0?

Comment: NanoCpus = 0 by default.
How to restore this value?

Comment: can you not set it to 0 like you set it to 1?

Comment: how to unlimit cpu?